# Making images in random position when every time mouse clicked

Tags: processing

I am doing my school project right now. But I have problem with it.

Here are the instructions:

1. Drawing three different-looking bottles on the screen. There should be a "cork" clearly visible on the top of each bottle.

Allowing the user to press any key to reset the scene. Resetting the scene means that the the screen is immediately re-drawn so that the only thing on it are the three bottles with their corks. The user can then click on the corks as if the program had been run for the first time. (Resetting the scene means erasing any apples sitting on the bottom of the screen (because they have fallen off the tree) and re-drawing them on the tree. If any apples happen to be in mid-air when the scene is reset, those falling apples should disappear.)

Draw the bottles in randomly chosen locations each time the program is run, or the scene is reset (by the user pressing any key). All parts of the bottles should always appear entirely on the screen, and no parts of any of the bottles should over-lap other bottles.

My question is I probably have to use mousePressed() statement to make my bottles image move into random positions when my mouse clicked. But I don't know what should I put under the mousePress() statement. I am now loading 3 images on the screen. Can anyone help with me?

Comment: Start smaller. Can you write a little example sketch that draws a single rectangle at a random location? Can you edit that sketch so the rectangle moves to a different random location whenever you click? Can you edit that sketch to show 3 rectangles? Can you edit that sketch to show images instead? Work your way up and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Comment: @Momoko Did your class cover arrays at this point ? What about functions ? classes  ? Also, are the bottle images the same dimensions ?